# equivalent of "Go to Folder window" in windows, to access a file in a windows open prompt located somewhere else from the current directory?

Tags: windows, automation

I am used on OSX to use CMD-Shift-g to open a Go to Folder window. What fundamentally does, is to open a file in a location without me using the mouse to navigate to a different directory. I paste the path of a file, like if I am loading a PSD in Photoshop, and I can load the file, independently from where my current directory is pointing at.

Is there an equivalent to this in Windows? Like if I have a file open prompt in Photoshop (or any other windows app, for what matters), that is pointing at my desktop, while my file is in some other location, and I can pass the full path of the file, like I do on OSX with the go to folder window?

Answer (score 0):

I found a "workaround". Windows fundamentally accept in the file name textfield, the full path too; so if you are on desktop for example, and in the file name field you type the full path of the file, it will in fact change the current directory to the full path you pass.

Works in a similar way but without the need to call a window to just change the path.